# Updating a variable value with jQuery, based on a map click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, mapbox-gl

I am working with a Mapbox GL map, similar to something like Leaflet or OpenLayers. For this case, I have allowed a click on the map to activate a popup with text from an attribute of that element of the map. I want this click to also update a variable, img_start, which contains a key for an image in street level view. I have the following code inside my `<script></script>` inside the `<body>`. The map element is inside the `<div id="map">` and the variable `img_start` is inside `<div id="mly">`. So I want a click on the map to update the `img_start` variable, then refresh the mly div. How can I achieve this, and what am I doing wrong?

Specific code I'm referring to:

```
  map.on('click', function (e) {
  //change img_start variable, right now just a test to see if the new value will load
  img_start = 'lGQKs30MWMrNJnTjDz-2Ig';
  //refresh the 'mly' div so the new start image appears
  $("#mly").load(location.href + " #mly");
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['parcels-layer'] });
    if (!features.length) {
        return;
    };

    var feature = features[0];

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(map.unproject(e.point))
        //displays the TaxIDNum of the parcel
        .setHTML(feature.properties.TaxIDNum)
        .addTo(map);
});

// Indicate that the symbols are clickable by changing the cursor style
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['parcels-layer'] });
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Full code of my HTML document, with the image viewer at the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Kelleys Island Parcels Demo</title>
<meta content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name=
'viewport'>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.24.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.24.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link href=
"https://npmcdn.com/mapillary-js@1.4.1/dist/mapillary-js.min.css" rel=
"stylesheet">
<style>
     body {
         width: 1350px;
         height: 480px;
         background-color: black;

     }

     a:link{
       color: ##e60000;
       text-decoration: none
     }
     a:visited{
       color: ##e60000;
       text-decoration: none
     }
     a:hover{
       color: ##e60000;
       text-decoration: none
     }
     a:active{
       color: orange;
       text-decoration: none
     }
     .title {
       color: white;
       font-family: "Century Gothic";
       font-size: 24px;
       text-align: center;
       font-weight: bolder;
     }
     .intro {
       color: white;
       font-family: "Century Gothic";
       font-size: 14px;
       text-align: center;
     }
     .mly-wrapper {
         position: relative;
         background-color: grey;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
     }

     .mapillary-js {
         position: relative;
         height: 100%;
         width: 50%;
     }

     #map {
         position: absolute;
         width: 50%;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         z-index: 100;
     }
     .mapboxgl-popup {
         max-width: 400px;
         font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
    Kelleys Island Parcels
</div>
<div class="intro">
    <br>
  Placeholder info
</div><br>
<div class="mly-wrapper">
    <div id='mly'></div>
    <div id='map'></div>
</div><button onclick="play()">Play</button><button onclick=
"stop()">Stop</button>
<script src=
"https://npmcdn.com/mapillary-js@1.4.1/dist/mapillary-js.min.js">
</script>
<script>
window.img_start = 'KXPQhn74azgtjJYcrGK-Fw';
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2JlZGRvdyIsImEiOiI5Q09YRG1RIn0.Izu6OPJ4CEEaSSpGuys3Xg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-82.69965,41.60116],
    zoom: 12
});



map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('parcels', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cbeddow/0bb1a957326cab0aec649e0dea3b978d/raw/f1069a486982efd0898cb915a7f39284fdd43321/kelleys_island.geojson'
    });

    // Add a layer showing the parcel polygons.
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'parcels-layer',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'parcels',
        'source-layer': 'parcels-layer',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 0.4)',
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 1)'
        }
    });
});


// When a click event occurs on a polygon, open a popup at the location of
// the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
map.on('click', function (e) {
  //change img_start variable, right now just a test to see if the new value will load
  img_start = 'lGQKs30MWMrNJnTjDz-2Ig';
  //refresh the 'mly' div so the new start image appears
  $("#mly").load(location.href + " #mly");
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['parcels-layer'] });
    if (!features.length) {
        return;
    };

    var feature = features[0];

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(map.unproject(e.point))
        //displays the TaxIDNum of the parcel
        .setHTML(feature.properties.TaxIDNum)
        .addTo(map);
});

// Indicate that the symbols are clickable by changing the cursor style
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['parcels-layer'] });
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
});


         var mly = new Mapillary.Viewer('mly',
             'UTZhSnNFdGpxSEFFREUwb01GYzlXZzpkMWM2YzdjYjQxN2FhM2Vh',  // ClientID 
             img_start, {cover: true, cache: false, direction: false});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get the concept of a variable (code) being inside a `div` (markup). Could  you elaborate?

Comment: Basically that variable is an image key, which allows http://website.com/img/<img_start>.jpg to retrieve an image. Instead, the javascript automatically fills that image key:

    `var mly = new Mapillary.Viewer('mly',
             'UTZhSnNFdGpxSEFFREUwb01GYzlXZzpkMWM2YzdjYjQxN2FhM2Vh',  // ClientID 
             img_start, {cover: true, cache: false, direction: false});`

the `img_start` variable there feeds the key to the script which retrieves that image from the server. So when I click on a point in the map, I'm trying to have it refer to an image associated with that map parcel.